# SendMessage function

Tags: python, c++, sendmessage

can I make the [SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx) function using python instead of c++?

I'm using python for desktop application that connecting to PHP in a web server!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [pywin32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/).

And use it like:

```
import win32api, win32con

hwnd = ... # obtain it using spy++, etc.

win32api.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_SHIFT, 0)
```